# foreign quotation marks in short citation

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I'm using the style `verbose-ibid`. My bibliography contains German, English and French articles. In the first appearance (fullcite) article names are in quotation marks according to their language. But in the second appearance (shortcite) they all come with the same quotation marks. I think in `verbose-ibid.cbx` it is

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
\printnames{labelname}%
\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
\printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
```

and in `biblatex.def` it is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

who are responsible but I'm by far not an expert. How can I change it to somehow use `foreignquote` instead of `\mkbibquote`?

Comment: Welcome. It would really help to have a small, compilable document showing the problem. Much easier for people to work on a solution which might actually help.

Comment: Welcome. Yes please show us a MWE that actually exhibits the problem. Does `language=auto` (instead of the default `language=autobib`) as loading-time option help? The problem should not lie with `\mkbibquote` which as far as I know is language-sensitive, but with the fact that `biblatex` does not switch the languages in citations while it does in the bibliography (by default) and so also in a fullcite because a fullcite is essentially just a call to the bib-driver.

Comment: <code>langauge=auto</code> solves the problem. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

To also make the citations use the environment specified via the `autolang` option, set

```
language=auto
```

The default value for this option is `autobib` which means that only in the bibliography language switching is enabled.